# Add days to Date then Format Date Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to add days to a date then format the date but getting this error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This is the query

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME
SET @date = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY,30,dbo.EJTable.Receipt_Date_Time) FROM dbo.EJTable)
SELECT FORMAT(@date, 'd', 'en-GB') as '*InvoiceDate'
FROM dbo.EJTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is very clear.  Just nest the functions.  You can't save a result set to a scalar variable:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, 30, t.Receipt_Date_Time) 'd', 'en-GB') as '*InvoiceDate'
FROM dbo.EJTable t;
```

Voila!  No variable needed at all.

Note that I also introduced a table alias so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Good answer & **Voila** is great ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use style `103` with  [**`convert()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for `en-GB` (dd/mm/yyyy) format.

```
select convert(char(10),dateadd(day,30,getdate()),103)
```

returns: `12/06/2017`

For your code, this would look like:

```
select convert(char(10),dateadd(day, 30, Receipt_Date_Time),103) as [*InvoiceDate]
from dbo.EJTable;
```

This provides the same result as the answer by Gordon Linoff, but `format()` can be slower, take a look here: [`format()` is nice and all, but… - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

---

Also, using string literals for aliases (e.g. `'*InvoiceDate'`) is deprecated. It is recommended to enclose aliases that contain special characters with square brackets instead (e.g. `[*InvoiceDate]`).